# What does an italicized ``n'' mean in an index entry of an old book?

Tags: indexing

The following snippet is from a the INDEX of book that was published in 1877:

[image]

I would like to know what the *n* means in, for example, the index entry

```
Acworth, George, 100, *n*.
```

I don't ever recall having seen this before. Is this, perhaps, some sort of prior convention?

In any case, it occurs frequently in the said index:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: What's on the referenced pages for those?  Acworth, George or Alcock, John, bishop of Ely?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I googled your query and found this:
https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/quicklinks/2017-08/indexing_instructions_for_authors_0.pdf
Endnotes are referred to by page (on which the text of the note appears), the letter “n,” and the note number, with no internal space (504n14). If a footnote is indexed, this is indicated by listing an “n” after the page number (52n); if more than one note is on a page, then the note number may be added (52n4)

Comment: That explains it. Thank you.